# How to troubleshoot JS

Tags: jquery

I am using AddThis social media widget which gives me an icon followed by a text descriptor to the right of the icon, as illustrated below.

[image]

The descriptor text is over-riding the content on my page and I want to remove it. I have written the following JQuery script to 'remove' the text. It works on [some pages](http://neilsphotos.com/weddings.php) but not [other pages](http://neilsphotos.com/portraits.php). How can I troubleshoot the problematic pages to find out what is causing the error and correct it?

```
<script>
    function test(){
        $(".addthis_follow_label").text(function(index, text) {
            return text.replace("Facebook", "");
                });
        $(".addthis_follow_label").text(function(index, text) {
            return text.replace("Twitter", "");
                });
        $(".addthis_follow_label").text(function(index, text) {
            return text.replace("Google Follow", "");
                });
        $('.addthis_toolbox.addthis_vertical_style').css('width', '32px');
        addthis.layers.refresh();
};
window.onload=test;
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know AddThis in general but why don't you add

```
.addthis_follow_label{
    display:none;
}
```

to your main css file?
That should solve your problem.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! It was such a much more simpler solution than JQuery.